# Can we suggest a review of a reviewer, or an evaluation of a person using the review queue heavily?

Tags: discussion, review

[On this review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/24928), the user selected *No Action Needed*... @rolfl edited this question after the review was done so evidently, action *was* needed.

[Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history) you can see the amount of times this user has used the *No Action Needed* button to get credit for a review; I haven't looked at all of these, but it looks rather fishy to me.

Normally I wouldn't say anything, but this user is going through a lot of reviews today, and a good portion of them are *No Action Needed*, and from that post it was obvious that there was something that could be done. What actions as a community can we take?

Comment: Hmm.. are we ripe for review audits?

Comment: related: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/first-post-review-queue-what-is-it

Comment: Are you all aware of anything like review audits or such happening on other SE sites?

Comment: @Phrancis http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work

Comment: not an answer to the question, but since I'm mentioned: I re-looked at the first couple of posts, and most of them have either not been edited by someone else, or contain only very minor edits. But I get your point, and I will be more careful with reviews in the future and use `skip` a bit more often (especially if I think that `No action Needed` would be the best response, in which case I will just always press `skip`).

Comment: @tim I use skip when I can't understand the answer/question because I don't know the coding language or the algorithm they are talking about, or if there is too much that needs to be done and I don't have time to do it.  otherwise if I understand what the question/answer is talking about I can decide if I like the answer or not, if I like the answer I can upvote, if I don't like the answer but it isn't "wrong" then I can say there is nothing for me to do here and click the "No Action Needed" there are a lot of meta info that can help you figure out how to use the review queue effectively.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: That may take even more bad reviews by more users, and them the community team would really have to determine if audits would benefit us.  I wouldn't worry about it right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Statistics for each reviewer's recommended actions (or inaction) are available.  Moderators should be checking those statistics, but we haven't been actively doing so.  The statistics would have revealed the anomaly that you pointed out.

Once we spot such problems, we can warn the reviewer, and if necessary, follow up with disciplinary action.

Comment: so this isn't something that a normal 20k user can do anything about?

Comment: What kind of 'disciplinary action'?

Comment: @Simon Warning, temporary review ban, and in extreme cases account suspension.

Answer (score 5):

If you've noticed something from a *specific user*, and they have at least one post, you can flag *any* of their posts and explain the situation.  It's not a big deal on a low-activity site like this, but doing so anyway can keep you anonymous and also give moderators a better starting point.

Comment: I know this was posted nearly 6 years ago... should we revise the wording on "_low-activity site_"?

Answer (score 3):

For a one-off user like this, I could see a moderator taking this user to a private chat room and giving them a chance to explain their reasoning, and perhaps the moderator can help clarify if *No Action Needed* truly is the correct selection, or what the user can do to help with the queue and actually "earn" the credit.